# Java: How to iterate over an ArrayList without using nested loops to insert key-value pair in HashMap

Tags: java, loops, arraylist, hashmap

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    
int key = 1, value = 1, counter = 0;

for(value = 1; value <= list.size(); ++value) {
    counter = list.get(value-1);
    while(counter != 0) {
        map.put(key, value);
        ++key;
        --counter;
    }
}
```

This is a nested looping solution I could come up with. I want to iterate over each element of ArrayList and run inner loop till the integer value becomes zero for every element of ArrayList, and insert key and value in HashMap.

I want to achieve this using a single loop only because for higher integer values this seems like a inefficient solution.

Thank You.

Comment: Try using Iterator.

Comment: If you tend to decrease the counter by one each time, then anyway you will have O(n*m) {n -> list size and m -> highest value in the list} worst case complexity. Doesn't matter if you use loop or not.

Comment: @DmanCannon I tried Iterator but I would still be required to use two loops, because outer loop has to run till ` itr.hasNext() `  and inner loop like this ` itr.next() != 0 ` to achieve same results.